# Need to detect the same application open on another computer on the network. Any software around that can do this?

Tags: windows, windows-networking

I have a time management application that I use at home quite a lot and have running most of the time.

At home, I have a desktop PC and a couple of laptops scattered around the house...all networked together.

Unfortunately, the application I use is not multi-user and I risk losing/corrupting data if it has been left running on one computer inadvertently while I start using it on another one in another part of the house.

I use Live Mesh to automatically keep the application's database synced across the different computers and I just need some way of making sure that I don't start using the application on another computer before closing it down on the previous one.

Anyone know of any Windows software that can detect if an application is running simultaneously on different computers on my network, and warn me if I am about to have two open at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [tasklist](http://commandwindows.com/tasklist.htm) which comes with Windows. It allows you to list processes, even on remote machines if you have the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any programs, but you could write a VB script and use that to launch the program.  In your script, query the [Win32_Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx) WMI object on each of the machine's on your network (I'm assuming this is a small number of machines, so you can just hardcode the references) and look for the running task.  You'd probably have to synchronise passwords across the machines to make it work.  [This page has a script you could use as a starting point](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_process.htm).